# Is there a way to play (rewind/fwd) a paused movie with left right gesture in objective c

Tags: objective-c, animation, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a video clip that will work like a intro video when application starts. Video contains many objects that comes from all directions and incorporates with each other.

I have two ways to do this:

- I start video in paused mode. Video goes forward or backward with finger left-right movement, exactly similar to the play strip of a `MPMoviePlayerController`. (video will remain paused and will not play)
- I make every object separate and inside a `UIScrollView` I move them as per the video describes with the help of `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` method.

2nd way is too complicated because the video is too lengthy and has near 45 objects. So how to go for 1st option?

Answer (score 0):

You should export your movie as a serie of image. Then use [UIImageView animationImages:listOfImages] and bind a UIGestureRecognizer on your imageView and display an image instead of another depending on the direction of the slide.